# The constructor SimpleGrantedAuthority(Set<Role>) is undefined this is the error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I got a error while coding please can any one solve this error
its shows change to return of getRoles() to string I changed it but still its asking error if I change in user there it will error

```
package com.deevia.otpGenaration.otpGenaration.service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.deevia.otpGenaration.otpGenaration.model.User;
import  com.deevia.otpGenaration.otpGenaration.repositories.UserRepository;

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRoles());
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
        user.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

Comment: the compiler is (of course) correct, there is only a constructor accepting a single `String role`, **not** a `Set<Role>`.

Answer (score 0):

it's normal to have that error since the `SimpleGrantedAuthority` constructor is accepting a `String` : `SimpleGrantedAuthority(java.lang.String role)`.

I don't know what is the return type of `getRoles()` from `com.deevia.otpGenaration.otpGenaration.model.User` class, but 
if it's a Collection of String you can use a stream to do the mapping 
`user.getRoles().stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());` and pass it to `UserDetails`